# brew change package install location

Tags: macos, homebrew

How can I change where Homebrew will install a package? Is this even possible? I tried manually moving the installed folder in `/usr/local/Cellar`, but the dynamic linking is "hardwired" for that location.

Comment: Why do you want to change the brew install location?

Comment: I need to access boost installed by gcc as well as boost installed by clang. I need access to both of these libraries at the same time.

Answer (score 19):

No it’s not possible. [You can change the location of the whole Homebrew install](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/664d0c67d5947605c914c4c56ebcfaa80cb6eca0/docs/Installation.md#untar-anywhere) (e.g. in `~/homebrew` instead of `/usr/local`) but you can’t change the location of *one* package.

Comment: How does one accomplish `You can change the location of the whole Homebrew install (e.g. in ~/homebrew instead of /usr/local) ` that?

Comment: @balupton See under "Untar anywhere" in the docs: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/664d0c67d5947605c914c4c56ebcfaa80cb6eca0/docs/Installation.md#untar-anywhere

Comment: As of Jan 2023, this answer works https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153639/201748

Comment: @samspot unless I’m missing something it works for casks but not for regular packages.

Comment: @bfontaine Ah ok, thanks, I didn't know there was a distinction between those two. I was googling how to change the location and found this question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS` env var or use command options like `--appdir` or `--cellar`.
see `man brew` for more details