# Printing Cyrillic text in Curses::UI

Tags: perl, curses

I am trying to print Cyrillic text in Curses::UI (this is the demo code with the label and the TextEditor of the code in russian):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Curses::UI;

use utf8;

my $cui = new Curses::UI( -color_support => 1 );
my @menu = (
    { -label => 'Файл',
        -submenu => [
            { -label => 'Exit      ^Q', -value => \&exit_dialog  }
        ]
    },
);
sub exit_dialog()
{
    my $return = $cui->dialog(
        -message   => "Do you really want to quit?",
        -title     => "Are you sure???",
        -buttons   => ['yes', 'no'],
    );

    exit(0) if $return;
}
my $menu = $cui->add(
    'menu','Menubar',
    -menu => \@menu,
    -fg  => "blue",
);
my $win1 = $cui->add(
    'win1', 'Window',
    -border => 1,
    -y    => 1,
    -bfg  => 'red',
);
my $texteditor = $win1->add("text", "TextEditor",
    -text => "привет!\n"
    . "Some Russian word.");
$cui->set_binding(sub {$menu->focus()}, "\cX");
$cui->set_binding( \&exit_dialog , "\cQ");
$texteditor->focus();
$cui->mainloop();
```

When I run the script, the Cyrillic is output in gibberish. Is there any way to fix this? I tried looking at the Language module but was not able to find anything helpful. I only saw that they use KOI8-R encoding, could this be something that I must take into account?

[image]

Other information: On MacOs, using perl version 5.34.0.

Comment: Looking at the [changelog](https://metacpan.org/release/MDXI/Curses-UI-0.9609/source/Changes), I doubt that it works properly with UTF-8 (too old).  Meanwhile, Perl uses UTF-8, and you'd have to convert your strings to KOI8-R (and have a suitable locale for this).

Comment: I see.. can you elaborate a bit on what 'having a suitable locale' means? I tried using Encode (e.g. encode("koi8r", $string)) but now it only prints out question marks!

Comment: @CauchyBoi What terminal emulator do you use? Which platform (unix, macOS, ..) ? Which version of perl ?

Answer (score 1):

`Curses::UI` dates from 2002/2003 (see [ChangeLog](https://metacpan.org/release/MDXI/Curses-UI-0.9609/changes)), which was right around the time that ncurses started providing wide-character support (e.g., [ncurses 5.3](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#other_versions) in 2002).  There's no indication in the `Curses::UI` change-log that its developers took any of that into account.

The ncurses [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) points out that to handle different character sets, an application has to call `setlocale` before calling `initscr`.  The [`Curses::UI`](https://metacpan.org/release/MDXI/Curses-UI-0.9609/source/lib/Curses/UI.pm#L283) code does not do that.  It could be done in the underlying Perl [curses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses) module.  According to the Perl [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses) that something that you will have to do for yourself: it is not automatic.

Without calling `setlocale`, ncurses will support ASCII.  Other characters will print as described in the [`unctrl`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-unctrl) manual page.

With calling `setlocale`, ncurses has an additional complication for Perl: the binding may use the narrow-curses or the wide-curses library.  The Perl curses [`Makefile.PL`](https://metacpan.org/release/GIRAFFED/Curses-1.38/source/Makefile.PL) has some logic to attempt to choose the latter (ymmv).

Beyond that — you'll have to find how to pass properly-encoded strings via the curses interface.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is if your script is saved as UTF-8 by your text editor. Then, try add

```
use utf8;
```

at the top of your script. This will tell Perl that your script is written in UTF-8. See the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8) for information.

However, it turns out that for this specific module this is not enough. [`Curses::UI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI) uses the [`Curses`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses) module to render the UI. The `Curses` module again loads the C library `libcurses`, or `libncurses`, or `libncursesw` library depending on what is installed on your system. In order to display wide characters (UTF-8) you need the last one `libncursesw`, see [ncurses.faq.html](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html).

On my laptop with Ubuntu 21.10 I have `libncursesw` version 6 (provided by package `libncurses-dev`), however on your mac you have not (from discussion in comments below) the wide character variant of libcurses, but `/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib` (from the comments below). You need to install the version with wide character support:

```
$ brew install ncurses
```

then reinstall the Perl `Curses` module (assuming you have homebrew version of perl installed):

```
$ wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/G/GI/GIRAFFED/Curses-1.38.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf Curses-1.38.tar.gz
$ cd Curses-1.38
$  brew info ncurses
ncurses: stable 6.3 (bottled) [keg-only]
Text-based UI library
https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3 (3,968 files, 9.6MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2022-02-22 at 00:08:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/ncurses.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
==> Caveats
ncurses is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
 
If you need to have ncurses first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
 
For compilers to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/include"
 
For pkg-config to find ncurses you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig"
 
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig" pkg-config --libs ncurses
-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/lib -Wl,-search_paths_first -lncursesw
 
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/lib/pkgconfig" pkg-config --cflags ncurses
-D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/include/ncursesw -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/include
 
# Run perl Makefile.PL with these settings:
$ CURSES_LIBTYPE=ncurses CURSES_LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/lib -Wl,-search_paths_first -lncursesw" CURSES_CFLAGS="-D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/include/ncursesw -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/include"  perl Makefile.PL
GEN    function:  not applicable
PANELS functions: not enabled
MENUS  functions: not enabled
FORMS  functions: not enabled
 
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Curses
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
 
# Then compile, test, and install the module
$ make
$ otool -L blib/arch/auto/Curses/Curses.bundle
blib/arch/auto/Curses/Curses.bundle:
    /opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/lib/libncursesw.6.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.0.0)
$ make test
$ make install
```

Still, even using the correct library version `libncursesw`  might not be enough to display UTF-8 correctly. If your current locale is not `UTF-8` the library will still use that locale's character encoding instead instead of `UTF-8`, see [the documentation](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) here. This means that you might need to add

```
use POSIX qw(locale_h);
use locale;
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8");
```

at the top of your program before using the library's functions.

Comment: I tried that, and nothing changed.. some of the characters that printed ok in cyrillic actually print in gibberish... I tried printing some cyrillic in a blank perl file and it printed correctly, so I believe that the issue is with how Curses::UI handles cyrillic..

Comment: @CauchyBoi Strange that seems to work for me. See the screenshot above. Can you update your question with a screenshot showing the problem ?

Comment: @CauchyBoi Another thing you can check is if your text-editor is saving the file (the script) as UTF-8 or some other encoding

Comment: Done (modified the code with adding use utf8) . I'm on MacOs using Vim (MacVim), and the encoding is set to utf-8...

Comment: @CauchyBoi Ok I am using Ubuntu 21.04. I will try this on macOS later see if it can be the platform.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! (using perl 5.34.0 to answer your other comment)

Comment: @CauchyBoi Yes tested this on macOS 12.0.1, perlbrew perl v5.34.0, iTerm2 terminal and it does not translate correctly as you also observed. I am looking into this

Comment: That is so weird! Let me know if you find something!

Comment: @CauchyBoi Note that `Curses::UI` uses [`Curses`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses) internally for rendering and I am able to reproduce this bug on macOS using `Curses` directly using [this script](https://pastebin.com/MEUXFRSZ). So I think the issue is in `Curses` on macOS.  I also note that macOS uses the C library `libcurses`, whereas on Linux `libncurses` is used instead. It might be the reason.

Comment: @CauchyBoi Strange, after I recompiled the modules and reinstalled `Curses` it now seems to work on macOS also. I also installed `ncurses` with `brew install ncurses`, but I do not think that's why it works now..

Comment: Tried removing and re-installing curses and installing ncurses, still nothing... Fudge!

Comment: @CauchyBoi I think you need to install the `Curses` module from source since you need to give explicit arguments to `Makefile.PL` about the location of the `libncurses.dylib` library. First can you try find out which library your current installation of `Curses` uses? For example like [this](https://pastebin.com/fWb6ku1w)

Comment: I get location 
`/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Curses.pm` 
, which differs from you. I also believe that I'm using perl that came 'out of the box' with my MacOS and didn't use perlbrew to install oerl. Could that influence something here?

Comment: Yes using the "system" perl on macOS can absolutely influence things! It is generally recommended to install a custom perl in addition to the system perl on macOS if you are planning to install additional Perl modules. However it seems you have already installed a second perl due to location you show for `Curses.pm`, namely `/usr/local/Cellar`, see [more](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/428356/122863) here. So you probably installed a second perl using [`brew install perl`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/perl) then ?

Comment: ... But first I am curious about which version of the curses library you are using. Can you provide the output of `otool -L  /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Curses/Curses.bundle` ?

Comment: Yes I had. And so if my perl compiles then I must be using the brew-installed perl and not the 'out-of-the' box MacOs perl. Unless Curses is installed at two places, which I highly doubt. The output is 
`usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Curses/Curses.bundle:
 /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)`.

Comment: Yes it seems you are using a different version of the ncurses library than I am. You are using `/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib` whereas I am using `/opt/homebrew/opt/ncurses/lib/libncursesw.6.dylib`. Can you try reinstall `Curses` from source like [this](https://pastebin.com/s8JqFm2t) ?

Comment: Looks like I'm issues with that as well... Here is the process: 
[link](https://pastebin.com/5S0n0VaJ)
Is there anything I am doing wrong here (pretty new to all of this..)?

Comment: @CauchyBoi The pastebin link seems to be "private". I am not able to open it.

Comment: Sorry about that! Changed to public.

Comment: @CauchyBoi Thanks for the update! What is the output of `brew info ncurses` ?

Comment: Thank you for the help! You're a live saver! Updated the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5S0n0VaJ)!

Comment: Notice from the output of `brew info ncurses` that I have installed it in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ncurses/6.3` whereas you have installed it in `/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.3`.. You need to change the paths accordingly

Comment: Question, is it even possible to change install location (as you can see, still struggling!) ? It may be that on my mac version (10.15.5) I must have homebrew install packages in `/usr/local` ? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622073/brew-change-package-install-location)

Comment: @CauchyBoi I think you misunderstood? What I proposed was not to change the installation path for homebrew, but to change the path you used when running `pkg-config`

Comment: Try this: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.3/lib/pkgconfig" pkg-config --libs ncurses`

Comment: Like this? [attempt 2](https://pastebin.com/dHKZ66mX)

Comment: You also need to change the paths when running `perl Makefile.PL` accordingly to the output you get from running `pkg-config`

Comment: The `make test` passed! See [attempt 3](https://pastebin.com/mBdjS8jW). I added the results of `perl -MCurses -E'say $INC{"Curses.pm"}'` and `otool`. Should I now be good to `cpanm Curses::UI` and re-run my code?

Comment: Great! Actually you should not need to reinstall `Curses::UI`, just try rerun your code..

Comment: I still get gibberish.. fudge (again!).. if I run `brew info ncurses` I still get `/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/6.3 (3,968 files, 9.3MB)`.. so could that mean that it's still reading from the wrong path? I had noticed if I wanted to run `brew uninstall ncurses` it wouldn't let me since it was a dependency for vim. Could that be something screwing things up?

Comment: Ok interesting, let's see if we can find out what is going on :) Can you try [this](https://pastebin.com/DH502jgH) simple script to test `Curses` module only ?

Comment: Done, got output: `testing: п @иве B`. So Curses itself is still acting up..

Comment: Just to check you do not have multiple versions installed, what is the output of `perl -MCurses -E'say $INC{"Curses.pm"}'` ? Then run `otool -L` on the `.bundle` file at that location and check that it is using `libncursesw.6.dylib`

Comment: It says that the file does not exist, see the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TUuKrvhx)..

Comment: Ok, great it seems it is loading the correct version of `libncursesw.6.dylib` (I forgot to mention that it is in the `auto` sub directory, but you figured it out) then. Next thing to try is to print out the dynamic libraries that are actually loaded when you load `Curses` from perl. First try to locate the absolute path of your perl binary, using `which perl`. Then try run: `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES <abs_path_to_perl> -MCurses -e1`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/euQuA6TT) is an example

Comment: Here it is: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/T2yqTpUD)

Comment: Ok everything looks good, so I am starting to believe this is related to the locale settings. Can you try [this](https://pastebin.com/tRsikbhi) simple C program ?

Comment: Or maybe try [this](https://pastebin.com/DsJJCNdu) Perl script first..

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) : *"The library uses the locale which the calling program has initialized."*

Comment: Ran the perl script, but I wasn't able to get the c script running, [see here](https://pastebin.com/fw54YzFA)..

Comment: Can you try to compile the C program like [this](https://pastebin.com/zDgkZMxh) ?

Comment: That works, I get output `Hello, привет!`. So that means perl isn't picking up the 'correct' ncurses?

Comment: I think the perl script is loading the correct library `libncursesw`, we tested this earlier with `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES ....`, I think it is more likely that it has something to do with the locale, or the encoding of the input string that is given to the library.. Can you try debug this further by making small changes to [the test script](https://pastebin.com/DsJJCNdu).  For example, start by passing an empty string to `setlocale` on line 12 (as we did in the C program)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response! I tried passing an empty string `setlocale`, still outputs `testing: п @иве B`. I am not sure what other kind of 'debugging' I can do from here.. any idea?

Comment: Hi. Ok, good then we try the next thing: to check if encoding input looks right. Can you try [this](https://pastebin.com/ThA3SJh8) modified script. When I run it I get "43F.440.438.432.435.442" for the unicode character values that are input (the content of the variable `$str`)

Comment: Ran it, I get `43F.440.438.432.435.442` as well.

Comment: Ok good.. then I think to get further it would be best to try a C debugger and set a breakpoint in the C library. Can you first try install a debugging version of `libcursesw` like [this](https://pastebin.com/sGiRiARk) ?

Comment: Done! What should I do next?

Comment: Good :) Then I suggest first testing the debugging library with [the simple C program](https://pastebin.com/tRsikbhi). Recompile it using [this](https://pastebin.com/tD2gN3tw) command. Test that it works by running the generated `./tcw` binary. Then test it with the debugger, for example like [this](https://pastebin.com/82MX9ndE)